# Mysql query string combine for result

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join these two mysql query string together for result columns like worker, product, Issued, received, pro_unitrs, pro_tot

First ==

```
select (select wor_code from chall_rec_master where rec_id = chall_rec_pro.rec_id) as Worker, pro_code, sum(pro_qty) as receive, pro_unitrs, pro_tot from chall_rec_pro group by pro_code
```

Second ==

```
select (select worker_code from challan_master where challan_id = challan_mast_prod.challan_id) as Worker , pro_code, sum(pro_qty) as Issued from challan_mast_prod group by pro_code
```

columns worker, product, Issued, received, pro_unitrs, pro_tot

Answer (score 0):

A union query should do the trick- pretty straightforward, just make sure you have the same number of columns returning (do things like NULL as pro_unitrs or '' as pro_unitrs where you wouldn't have the information the other query has... 
mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

```
select * from 
((
    select 
    (select wor_code from chall_rec_master where rec_id = chall_rec_pro.rec_id) as Worker, 
    pro_code, 
    sum(IFNULL(pro_qty,0)) as receive, 
    '' as Issued,
    pro_unitrs, 
    pro_tot 
    from chall_rec_pro 
    group by pro_code
) UNION (
    select (select worker_code from challan_master where challan_id = challan_mast_prod.challan_id) as Worker , 
    pro_code, 
    '' as receive,
    sum(IFNULL(pro_qty,0)) as Issued,
    '' as pro_unitrs,
    '' as pro_tot 
    from challan_mast_prod 
    group by pro_code
)) as results
```

--edit-- updated query to include both receive and Issued
--edit2-- updated query to not sum null values - MySQL's `sum()` will null the output if it tries to sum a null value, so put `ifnull()` inside it to set the variable to zero if it's null.

Comment: No from your query string I get Worker, pro_code, receive, pro_unitrs, pro_tot whereas pro_unitrs and pro_tot showing null or blob only and one more column missing i.e., Issued ?

Comment: columns like worker, product, Issued, received, pro_unitrs, pro_tot

Comment: Now I get the columns but no values only Null or blob in  Issued, received, pro_unitrs, pro_tot

Comment: Same result null or blob

Comment: Where do `challan_mast_prod` and `chall_rec_pro` come from? You seem to be referencing table aliases that don't exist...